# Insert row in dataframe between every existing row and it must contain information from the previous and next rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Okay this one I'm a little bit stuck on.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
             time  Throttle   Vout
0      1056.65785      1      8
1      1056.66255      2      8
2      1056.66785      3      9
3      1056.67330      4      11
4      1056.67840      5      15
```

and I need to add a row between every existing row - the whole dataset is about 21000 rows. The `time` should be equal to the `time` in the next row. Any **other** columns should have the values of the previous row.

So the outcome would be something like this:

```
             time  Throttle   Vout
0      1056.65785      1      8
1      1056.66255      1      8   <---- new row
2      1056.66255      2      8
3      1056.66785      2      8   <---- new row
4      1056.66785      3      9
5      1056.67330      3      9   <---- new row
6      1056.67330      4      11
7      1056.67840      4      11   <---- new row
8      1056.67840      5      15
```

I've looked into df.apply() but not sure where to start

**Serge Ballesta** answer:

So this works with the test data supplied above. When I test it on a much larger DataFrame I start to see some errors. I originally thought it was something wrong in my PyCharm but testing with a larger dataset in powershell proved otherwise.

[image: Serge Ballesta answer]

**Quang Hoang** answer:

So this also worked on a small scale but when using a larger dataset it seemed to have quite a few issues with both time and the other columns. I've highlighted some in the image below. The top df is the original and the bottom is the altered.

[image: Quang Hoang answer]

**Valdi_Bo** Answer

The additional columns seemed to work well with this but there seems to be an issue with the times columns on larger datasets. I've highlighted some below.

[image: Valdi_Bo answer]

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `concat` and `ffill`:

```
(pd.concat([df, df[['time']].shift(-1)])
   .sort_index(kind='mergesort')
   .dropna(how='all')
   .ffill()
)
```

Output:

```
         time  Throttle  Vout
0  1056.65785       1.0   8.0
0  1056.66255       1.0   8.0
1  1056.66255       2.0   8.0
1  1056.66785       2.0   8.0
2  1056.66785       3.0   9.0
2  1056.67330       3.0   9.0
3  1056.67330       4.0  11.0
3  1056.67840       4.0  11.0
4  1056.67840       5.0  15.0
```

Comment: I have updated the original question with errors from this answer :)

Comment: please see update with `kind='mergesort'` which is stable.

Answer (score 1):

I would build a copy of the dataframe, shift its `time` column, concatenate it to the original dataframe and sort the result according to `time`:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2['time'] = df['time'].shift(-1)
result = 

df2[~df2['time'].isna()].append(df).sort_values('time').reset_index(drop=True)
```

It gives as expected:

```
         time  Throttle  Vout
0  1056.65785         1     8
1  1056.66255         1     8
2  1056.66255         2     8
3  1056.66785         2     8
4  1056.66785         3     9
5  1056.67330         3     9
6  1056.67330         4    11
7  1056.67840         4    11
8  1056.67840         5    15
```

Comment: Hmm this works as it should in console but when I view the df in pycharm it seems to have scrambled up a bit...

Comment: I have updated the original question with errors from this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This might look a bit overwhelming, but the idea is that you merge the original dataframe with its copy whose values in Throttle & Vout columns are shifted by 1:

```py
pd.concat([
  df,
  df.loc[:,'Throttle':].shift(1).combine_first(df)
]).reset_index().loc[1:,].sort_values(['time', 'Throttle'])
```

Answer (score 0):

First compute an auxiliary DataFrame - a copy of *df*, with *time* column
shifted 1 place up and without the last original row:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2.time = df2.time.shift(-1)
df2.dropna(inplace=True)
```

The result, for your input sample, is:

```
         time  Throttle  Vout
0  1056.66255         1     8
1  1056.66785         2     8
2  1056.67330         3     9
3  1056.67840         4    11
```

and these are the new rows to insert.

To get a concatenation of these 2 DataFrames, in proper order, run:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df2], keys=[1, 2]).swaplevel().sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

To guarantee the proper order of rows, I added to the previous solution:

- `keys` - to add "origin indicators", but they area added as the **top**
  level of the MultiIndex,
- `swaplevel` - swap levels of the MulitiIndex, to provide proper sort
  by index (in the next step).

Comment: I have updated the original question with errors from this answer :)